# User defined variables are executed twice in jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I tried to use variable in jasper report. I created a list component as below.

```
<componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="426" height="50" uuid="a99e79ba-74a6-4224-a1e5-d8b8d557a42f"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset2" uuid="61554b87-1110-4c24-848a-c74c83ca33aa">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="50" width="426"/>
                </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```

For list data source, I added three elements ("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"). Then I create a variable inside the data set like

```
<subDataset name="dataset2" uuid="c2f92ca6-ab45-4b91-89f6-2ca7a4c80d4e">
        <variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.String">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA["Variable Value";System.out.println("Variable")]]></variableExpression>
            <initialValueExpression><![CDATA["Initial Value";System.out.println("Initial")]]></initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
</subDataset>
```

When I print out in console, the output is

```
Initial 
Variable 
Variable 
Variable 
Variable 
Variable 
Variable
```

Seems that the variable is executed for every iteration of the list. But I wonder why the variable is executed **twice for each iteration**(3 X 2) and how to prevent that? The problem gives me a big headache when I tried to put the value into a list or want to append a StringBuilder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.